# Rails form label capitalization issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

In the show view of my user controller, I'm having an issue with the user's name not being capitalized in a label tag. The code is

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label "Assign " + @user.name + " to" %>
  <%= f.collection_select :id, @ders, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

The user's name appears something like `Example User` outside of the `form_for` block when called with `@user.name`, but inside the block it appears as `example user`. Why is that?

Comment: Is `#name` an attribute in your `User` model or a helper method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing to `<%= f.label :id, "Assign #{@user.name} to" %>`, `:id` is the value used for the `for` property on the label.